# Displaying a list of charts selected from a month selection in drop-down

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, dropdown

I am new to `Highcharts` and `JS`. For each month I have 5 charts. Here I am just sharing 5 example charts. I have to create a drop-down menu with each menu item for each month. When I select a month, all the charts for that month should be displayed in their divs. Default month should be current month. How could I do this?

Here’s my code so far:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="container1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="container2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="containerx"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="container3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="container4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    title: {
        text: 'Pie point CSS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        keys: ['name', 'y', 'selected', 'sliced'],
        data: [
            ['Apples', 29.9, false],
            ['Pears', 71.5, false],
            ['Oranges', 106.4, false],
            ['Plums', 129.2, false],
            ['Bananas', 144.0, false],
            ['Peaches', 176.0, false],
            ['Prunes', 135.6, true, true],
            ['Avocados', 148.5, false]
        ],
        showInLegend: true
    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2000',
        data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2016',
        data: [1216, 1001, 4436, 738, 40]
    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('containerx', {
    title: {
        text: 'Pie point CSS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        keys: ['name', 'y', 'selected', 'sliced'],
        data: [
            ['Apples', 29.9, false],
            ['Pears', 71.5, false],
            ['Oranges', 106.4, false],
            ['Plums', 129.2, false],
            ['Bananas', 144.0, false],
            ['Peaches', 176.0, false],
            ['Prunes', 135.6, true, true],
            ['Avocados', 148.5, false]
        ],
        showInLegend: true
    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container3', {
    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container4', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

The fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/hwm213dt/5/

Comment: Try adding a dropdown; hook up a callback function for when it changes selection - then in there change the data for the charts - just try plugging away at it and then ask further stuff in here with specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to prepare the perfect solution without taking a closer look on your whole application. The way of implementation hardly depends on your data structure and the chart types which you need to use, but I prepared the general example which shows how it could be done.

First I prepared the data so that it would be assigned for each month. Then I added the `onchange` listener on `dropdown` element, and update all charts by the new data from data object defined before, using built-in method `Chart.update()`. I left comments in my code, so you can read what happening "step by step", but If some part is not understandable or unclear for you, just ask in comment below this answer.

```
var months = {} // Will be the object with data structure for each month
var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown-months')
var options = dropdown.querySelectorAll('option')
var currentMonthId = new Date(Date.now()).getMonth()
var currentMonthName;

// Create random initial data
options.forEach(elem => {
  months[elem.value] = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    months[elem.value].push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100))
  }
  // Additionally, select current month in dropdown
  if (elem.value === Object.keys(months)[currentMonthId]) {
    currentMonthName = Object.keys(months)[currentMonthId]
    elem.selected = true
  }
})

dropdown.onchange = function() {
  var selectedMonth = this.value
  // Update all charts by new data
  Highcharts.charts.forEach(chart => {
    chart.update({
      series: [{
        data: months[selectedMonth]
      }]
    })
  })
}

// Generate charts and fill them by current month data
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  Highcharts.chart('container' + i, {
    series: [{
      data: months[currentMonthName]
    }]
  })
}
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/yacrdfo0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update